# How can I use rockwool for indoor gardening?

Tags: plant-health, indoors, soil, plant-recommendations, hydroponic

So, I decided to do research on using rock-wool for my indoor panting needs, rather than the potting soil I obtain from the local stores here. Reasons are
1. I have some rock-wool leftover after insulating my arctic.
2. It is extremely light to handle
3. Less dirt indoor
4. Makes for easier examination of plant roots, and transplanting.

Now, even though this is what I intend to do this winter, I am not 100% yet about the idea, nor do I have a setup to handle watering, preventing fungi, algae from growing in the rock-wool containers over time. So I would appreciate some suggestions on how to make this work for me this winter.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Insulation material is not the same as rockwool for plants, rendering your first point moot.

Answer (score 2):

> I have some rock-wool leftover after insulating my arctic.

...Basically, what you have is insulation, not rockwool. You will be unable to grow plants in it.

You may want to look into hydroponics, based on your stated preferences.